# Find the missing number in this grid

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

[image]

Find the missing number in this grid. I am unable to find any pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is

> -19 
>  The above number is exactly in the middle of the 2 bottom numbers 
>  
> So the difference between 9 and -5 is 14, just subtract 14 from -5

Comment: In that case it should be -19.

Comment: @Wa Kai: That would be true if the question mark was on top of 9 and -5, but it's not.

Comment: Guys you are right.  Corrected it.

Comment: No, look every number is average of two numbers below it, so -5 is average of 9 and that question mark.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is

> -19.

Because

> Every number is mean of two digits exactly below it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, i edited your post with spoiler tags, it's common practice to hide the answers from those people that want to have a crack at the puzzles themselves.

Answer (score -1):

answer is -19 because above number is the half of the sum of two numbers in the bottom row